# Error displaying data in nodejs Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to show the necessary data of an API in a table, for that I am using nodejs and .ejs. When loading the view into the browser, I get the following error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: You cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. This is the code of the route that is responsible for loading movements.ejs

```
router.get('/movimientos',  (req, res, next) => {
  dbConnection.query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[WMS_Movimientos]", (err, result) => {
    console.log(result.recordsets[0].length)
    console.log(result)
    res.render('movimientos', {
      movTable : result
    });
  });
})
```

And the following is the view code:

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">Name
  
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Position
  
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Office
  
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Age
  
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Start date
  
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Salary
  
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < movTable.recordsets[0].length; i ++) { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Empresa %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Nro_Dcto %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Tipo_Dcto %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Barras %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Codigo %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Descripcion %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Bodega %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_bodega_Origen %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Bodega_Destino %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Und_Medida %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Und_Empaque %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].cantidad %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Observaciones %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Fecha %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Prioridad %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Nit_Responsable %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Usuario %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Cod_Centro_Costos %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Nro_Dcto_Cliente %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Fecha_procesado %></td>
          <td><%= movTable.recordsets[0][i].Estado %></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Position
        </th>
        <th>Office
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
        <th>Start date
        </th>
        <th>Salary
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

I have tried to solve the error by configuring the route asynchronously, but it still shows the same error when I want to execute the code.

This is my server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const engine = require('ejs-mate');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');


;//Inizializando
const app = express();
require('./routes/database');
require('./passport/local-auth');


//middlewares




app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//settings
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.signupMessage = req.flash('signupMessage');
    app.locals.signinMessage = req.flash('signinMessage');
    app.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
require('./routes/index')

//Starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log("Server on port ", app.get('port'))
});
```

Comment: You should probably look into your server code because the error is most likely in reference to the server-side of your application, the `movimientos` resourse.

Comment: In the console I can see the response of the server and it's fine

Comment: Since I don't know which server you are using (express, restify, something else), its probably the fact that you are not calling `next()`. When the request comes, the function that you pass to it, in your case the `(req, res, next) { ... }` part, is executed and it does not wait for the db code to execute. The response is sent. After that, your db query finishes and renders the page. Try calling `next()` in your db callback function.